# Vimscript - how can i check if a character is present in a variable

Tags: vim, match, string-matching, neovim

i am trying to make a function that returns only parts of the `getcwd()` value.

So, what i wanted, was something like

```
function! FileDir()
    let file_dir == getcwd()
    if file_dir "has more than three backlashes"
       return 'mycommand'
    else 
       return 'mycommand2'
endfunction
```

So i want to add something that does this: if getcwd() returns more than three directories, like, let's say: `/home/hrq/project-folder`, i want to add an specific `if` command to it. If returns two or less folders, like just `/home/hrq`, i want to add an `else` command, that i will add both later.

So i though that maybe i could check if it has, like, three backlases in the output of `getcwd()`

and i tried with the `match` expression, the `max`, the `len`, but i wasn't able to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple actually:

```
let l:slash = exists('+shellslash') && !&shellslash ? '\' : '/'
if count(getcwd(), l:slash) > 3
    ...
else
    ...
endif
```